# Autohotkey reducing the size of my code by using code within code (i cant remember what it's called sorry!)

Tags: autohotkey

I've made a big script in autohotkey to help me grind items in idle games, and it needs to have some code repeated a lot of times for each building so i want to condense it down to a single line, i think it might be called variables or classes in regular programming but it doesn't seem to be that for autohotkey, i cant for the life of me figure out how to create something like a keyword that has code inside it, i'm not even sure what to call it so i cant google it. like if it was

The actual code is like this, but a fair bit longer and i want to add multiple if statements later for different button press options

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------Building 1
splashtexton,500,100,Building,1
if (Building1 = 1){
Sleep, 2001
send {R DOWN}
Sleep, 1000
send {R UP}
Sleep, 100
send {U}
}Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------Building 2
splashtexton,500,100,Building,2
if (Building2 = 1){
Sleep, 2001
send {E DOWN}
Sleep, 1000
send {E UP}
Sleep, 100
send {U}}
Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
```

But i'd rather have something like

```
(Reuse this code)
Sleep, 2001
send {R DOWN}
Sleep, 1000
send {R UP}
Sleep, 100
send {U}

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------Building 1
splashtexton,500,100,Building,1
if (Building1 = 1){
(Reuse this code)
}
Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------Building 2
splashtexton,500,100,Building,2
if (Building2 = 1){
(Reuse this code)
}
Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
```

Then every time i write "this group" it repeats those commands, instead of me having to write the same code every time. I've gotten so far with making everything, and i would be perfectly capable of copy pasting the same code like 100 times but it would get very messy very quickly!

Can anyone point me in the right direction sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @0x464e said:

```
splashtexton,500,100,Building,1
if Building1 = 1
    function_name_here()
Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
splashtexton,500,100,Building,2
if Building2 = 1
    function_name_here()

Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
Return

function_name_here() {
    Sleep, 2001
    send {R DOWN}
    Sleep, 1000
    send {R UP}
    Sleep, 100
    send {U}
}
```

In this code, you can even use without "if's", because there are no parameters to be passed and validate/used.. So just:

```
splashtexton,500,100,Building,1
function_name_here()
Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
splashtexton,500,100,Building,2
function_name_here()

Sleep, 1001
send {Q}
Return

function_name_here() {
    Sleep, 2001
    send {R DOWN}
    Sleep, 1000
    send {R UP}
    Sleep, 100
    send {U}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is doable in so many ways, and what the best way would be depends fully on what the code is that you want to repeat.
If the code is as simple as your example shows, then a [function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm) might be what you want.

```
1::
    DoStuff()
return

2::
    DoStuff()
return

3::
    DoStuff()
return

DoStuff()
{
    Send, hello
    ToolTip, % "This computer has been up for " A_TickCount " ms."
    Sleep, 1000
    ToolTip
}
```

Comment: I cant figure out how to add a comment with code in it to show you the actual code so i've edited my origional post to have exactly what i'm working with sorry!